# swiftに関する質問

Tags: swift

```
//列挙型定義
enum Result: Int {
    case Success = 0
    case Error = 9
    func getMsg() -&gt; String {
        switch self {// self にデータが入ってくる
            case .Success:
                return &quot;OK&quot;
            case .Error:
                return &quot;NG&quot;
        }
    }
}
```

上記のコードの`-&gt;`ってなにを表しているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`&gt;`はHTMLやXMLで「>」を表す特別な書き方です。HTMLやXMLでは「>」や「<」はタグに使われるので、タグの意味ではなく単に記号を書きたい場合に使用します。

おそらく、参照されたサイトの不具合で本来は「>」と表示されるべきところが、`&gt;`のままになってしまったのでしょう。

つまり、そこは

```
func getMsg() -> String {
```

となるので、`getMsg()`という引数なしで、Stringを返すメソッドになります。